# Storing date range in cache keys

Tags: java, caching, memcached, ehcache

My db row has sample data as below

Example

```
StoreId    ProductId  Eff_Date         End_Date       Discount  
123        456        01-01-2001       12-31-2001     10%  
123        456        01-01-2002       12-31-2002     15%
```

When a customer comes in, my code checks discount something like 
select discount from table where storeId='123' and productId='456' and current_date<= EndDate and current_date>=Eff_date.

This works absolutely fine.

We need to store above data in cache. How can we store these date ranges in cache keys so that when customer purchases an item, we hit the right cache Key-value pair.

FYI, We haven't decided what caching framework to use. Please let me know what caching framework will support this requirement.

Thanks.

Comment: Joda Time as a time manipulation API has an `Interval` class which you can find useful here...

Comment: Yes, [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) [Interval](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html) may be helpful. But note that it is "half-open" where beginning of the span of time is inclusive, the ending exclusive. This approach is generally a good one for span-of-time work. So in your case, the `End_Date` would be the first day of following year, not the last day of the target year. Also, if there is *any* chance of your business ever dealing with other time zones, then you should be using date-time (`DateTime`) values not date-only (`LocalDate`) values.

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to implement something similar. I'm trying to retrieve multiple data from Github and store it according to Timestamp. I would be using it as: name of the file + timestamp as a Key and file result as Value.

### Key

I would suggest to use STOREID + PRODUCTID + End_DATE as key. You can concatenate all these 3 using a Delimiter.

### Value

Discount %

### Solution

- From End date you can easily get the Eff_date ie 1st Jan of the same Year
- You can use ConcurrentLinkedHashMap which is thread safe.
- Now get keySet from your map and use a function to loop through keys and break down keys into 3 seperate variables and find if your condition satisfies it.
- Eg. your req. is for Store 123 & Product 456 check discount on 03rd July 2002
- Key returned from map is '123/456/12-31-2002'
- Split on "/", now take first and second entry to verify if Store & Product Id matches
- Then check if date lies between  01-01-2002 & 12-31-2002, if yes then you've met all conditions and return the main Key.
- Now get the value for this key.

This is bit unconventional and may seem long but would save unnecessary DB calls.